# How to setup django permissions along TDD?

Tags: django, permissions, tdd, django-south, usergroups

I would like to use the default django permissions in my project. Base is that there are 3 types of users, a super user and two other distinct type of users. I'm working towards a system with groups and permissions. So add the two different types of users to their groups on creation.

The whole project is TDD (pure for learning TDD) and that means I want to test the permission system all over the project. But testing in Django happens with creating a new db on every test run.

Thats where my problem is. I would like on creation of the db (maybe better on launching server) to create my groups and set permissions on the groups. I'm thinking about south, but that means adding al lot of migration files on every push to the 'master' branch.

Is there a way to run a command on 'runserver' (or something similar) that checks if there are groups, and update/create the permissions on those groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide initial data in a fixtures directory (fixtures/initial_data.json) and they will be loaded in your test created db.

[Initial data doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/)